# Jenkins doesn't launch the android application

Tags: android, jenkins

I am trying to configure Jenkins for CI. I am able to get the android emulator launched and the build does succeed but the app is never launched. Only in the console it displays build successful but I don't see the app being launch in emulator.

What can be the reason for the same ?

Comment: i dont think so it is possible.. correct me if im wrong.

Comment: How are you launching the emulator in your Jenkins build, and how are you launching the app?

Comment: @ChristopherOrr - The way the Jenkins project is configured it launches the emulator which is mentioned in "Run existing emulator". For launching the app the path to apk is mentioned in "Install Android Package". Is there something that I am missing ?